# Why does a public type declared in the same class that it's being called from need to be instantiated?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-8

With this code:

```
var locationsInDB = from TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataDefinition location in
                        TaSLs_SQLCELocation.TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataDefinitions
                    where location.SavedToCloud = false
                    select location;
```

...I get,

> "*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'TaSLS_PhoneApp.MainPage.TaSLs_SQLCELocation'*"

I've got TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataContext declared in a separate class:

```
public class TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataContext : DataContext
{
    public static string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/gr8GooglyMoogly.sdf";

    public TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    { }

    public Table<TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataDefinition> TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataDefinitions;
}
```

I can't make TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataContext static because it implements DataContext

If I instantiate that class like so:

```
TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataContext tsldc = new TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataContext();
var locationsInDB = from TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataDefinition location in
                    tsldc.TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataDefinitions
                    where location.SavedToCloud = false
                    select location;
```

...I then get,

> "*'TaSLS_PhoneApp.TaSLs_Data.TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataContext' does not
>   contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments*"

What argument is it expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expecting the connection string

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is expecting the connection string as defined by the constructor:

```
public TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataContext(string connectionString)
```

Still, as you don't instantiate your table in your code you will get a null reference exception later on.

Comment: I didn't show all of my data code; what precisely do you mean by that (instantiating my table)? I followed the tutorial here step-by-step: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: instantiate means that you create the table somewhere. Probably with new Table<TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataDefinition>();.

Comment: I know what instantiate means; what I'm unclear about is just which abstraction of table being instantiated was being mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question "Why does a public type declared in the same class that it's being called from need to be instantiated?" you need to omit the class name - in this case 'TaSLs_SQLCELocation' and access your class property via the this keyword.

That only works, though, if you want to access your property 'TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataDefinitions' from within the class that property is defined - in your case 'TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataContext'

Try this:

```
var locationsInDB = from TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataDefinition location in
                    this.TaSLs_SQLCELocationDataDefinitions
                where location.SavedToCloud = false
                select location;
```

Comment: Trying that, I get, "Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer"